# how to access application without entering name second time

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder4.5

I have a application, in which when user open it up on their iPad, first view is about entering user name to access application. it works fine. Every time when I start application every time it ask me for a Name. But I have to remove that function that when user open application 2nd time, third time, ...... instead asking for username, application start from right after page of login(which is second page).

I know that in .net we can manage it by web.config file. Any one can help how to do that in flash builder 4.5?

Answer (score 1):

Use an [SharedObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/UsingSDK/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf6167e-7fcf.html) to store persistence status locally that you can just access then with SharedObject.getLocal() method. After that it's just a simple step of "skipping" the name asking part.